# How to reverse proxy another website within Wordpress

Tags: plugins

In WordPress, how can you reverse proxy another website into a WordPress site so it appears as one complete site?

So reverse proxy:
https://example.com

And have it appear as:
https://example.net/othersite
example.net is a WordPress site.